# How to make a query based on ID in react native with graphql?

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo

I want to make a query based on `job_id: ID!` but seem like something I am doing wrong and I want to understand what.

So here I am taking the job id.

```
render() {
 const { job } = this.props.navigation.state.params;
 const job_id = job._id;
 ........
}
```

So now I want to use that `job_id` for my query here

```
const GET_APPLICATIONS = gql`
  query getJobApplicationsForThisJob($job_id: ID!) {
    getJobApplicationsForThisJob(job_id: $job_id) {
      _id
    }
  }
`;

const DELETE_JOB = gql`
  mutation deteleJob($_id: ID!) {
      deleteJob(_id: $_id) {
        message
      }
    }
`;

const mutationConfig = {
    props: ({ mutate, ownProps }) => ({
        deleteJob: (_id) => mutate({ variables: { _id } }),
        ...ownProps,
    })
}

export default compose(
    withApollo,
    graphql(GET_APPLICATIONS, { name: "getApplications" }),
    graphql(DELETE_JOB, mutationConfig)
)(JobDetails);
```

But I end up with the following error

`Invariant Violation: The operation 'getJobApplicationsForThisJob' wrapping 'JobDetails' is expecting variable 'job_id' but it was not found in the props passed to 'Apollo(JobDetails)'`

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

I have used the HOC like this

```
export default compose(
    withApollo,
    graphql(GET_APPLICATIONS, { name: "getApplications", options: (props) => ({ variables: { job_id: props.navigation.state.params.job._id } }) }),
    graphql(DELETE_JOB, mutationConfig)
)(JobDetails);
```